# If $(a , b , c)$ is a Pythagorean triple, then so is $(ka , kb , kc)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, pythagorean-triples

From trigonometry text:

> Show that if $(a , b , c)$ is a Pythagorean triple then so is $(ka , kb , kc)$ for any integer $k > 0$. How would you interpret this geometrically?

Can someone please give a visual proof if possible?

Comment: "If the sides are proportional,are the triangles similar?" What's your definition of similarity?

Comment: If that is an answer to my question, then please, clarify what it means. It's just a random collection of symbols at the moment.

Comment: @5xum Wikipedia gives only one definition ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)#Similar_triangles)), with the only possible differences in definitions being excluding congruent triangles from being similar.

Comment: I think he means the criterions for similarity. The S is for Side and the A is for Angle.

Comment: @user26486 Yeah, that definition from wikipedia is pretty strange. It says that the triangles are similar if they have congruent angles and proportional sides, when in fact, each one of those properties implies the other. And if OPs definition of similarity is "the sides are proportional", then the answer is obvious.

Comment: @5xum You need to prove three sides being proportional implies the angles being equal. The proofs of the properties (which are theorems) that I've seen are not trivial, though simple.

Comment: @user26486 Which is precisely why I asked the OP what his definition of similarity is. The definition could be "if the sides are proportional", or it could be "if the angles are congruent", or it could be "if the sides are proportional *AND* the angles are congruent". Depending on which definition OP uses, the answer to the question changes drastically. Hence, my asking what his definition is.

Comment: Also, Aditya Chintalapati, you should realise that if you ask a question and then do not answer to any questions, your question will get downvoted, closed and deleted.

Comment: @5xum, i looked up the proof that three sides proportional implies three congruent angles and similarity. Is the answer to the actual question that trivial?

Comment: @5xum All the other definitions you suggest are weak and I see no reason why anyone would ever use them. If you see "because the triangles are similar,...", you'll never see anything like "then by theorem 1 all the sides and angles are congruent, so angles ABC, A'B'C' are equal" - you'll just see "angles ABC, A'B'C' are equal". If you still feel someone would use a different definition, then fine.

Comment: @user26486 Chill out. I don't know what definition OP is using, that's all. I learned my math by starting with the congruent angles definition. I guess now I'm weak.

Comment: @5xum Was it written in your textbook? If so, then sorry and that's a reasonable question to ask OP.

Comment: @user26486 I don't remember exactly as it was years ago. I do remember proving a theorem that the congruent angles definition and the proportional sides definition are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** The formula answer makes it easy:

For a,b,c; $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 $.  To verify ka,kb, and kc: $(ka)^2 + (kb)^2 = (kc)^2 $

$$(kc)^2 = k^2(c^2) = k^2(a^2 + b^2) = k^2a^2 + k^2b^2 = (ka)^2 + (kb)^2 $$

Here's a simple visual answer.  You were correct, if the sides are proportional, then the triangles are similar.  So, here are two 3/4/5 triangles, one in metric and one in inches:

[image: Metric Triangles]

[image: Imperial Units]